# How to parse intagram data json with python 2.7?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, parsing

I've got a json file of instagram followers that I'm trying to import into python to manipulate further. I've tried several methods to get all followers into a list or export to CSV but can't seem to iterate through the json properly.

This is the json structure:

```
{
    close_friends:  {
        user1: 2019-02-12T04:57:38
    },
    follow_requests sent:   {
        user2: 2019-02-01T11:27:37
    },
    followers:  {
        user3:2019-02-12T02:14:40,
        userN:YYYY-MM-DDTXX:XX:XX
    }
}
```

I've tried a few different solutions I've found here, tweaked for my context, but keep getting different errors.

```
import json
parsed_json = json.loads("test.json")
print parsed_json["followers"]
```

This gives me a "ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded" error. I'm reading into json documentation but can't figure out if my json is not formatted properly (missing quotes, or not flattened).

My goal is to have a list with all follower names (so user3 to userN).
Is there any simple way to achieve this with python?

Thank you.

Comment: Both the keys and values in your example data are strings, and so should quoted to be valid json.  Try creating the dictionary that you expect, and then call `json.dumps` on it, to see the expected format.

Comment: This isn't valid JSON. The keys and values must all be quoted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) `json.loads` takes an actual JSON string, not a file name.

You would need `json.load(f)`, where `f` is a file-handle.

2) Your keys and string-values (like dates) must all be surrounded by quotes, as per the JSON specification to be valid

---

FWIW, any new Python development should be using Python3, as Python2 will be deprecated soon (2020).

Comment: Thank you - there aren't any quotes in the source file provided directly from Instagram in their "download account data" feature though - do I need to edit the file before going forward?

Comment: I'm not sure how you are viewing the data, but your browser plugin might be hiding the quotes on its own. I don't think any API will produce bad-formatted data intentionally

Comment: You are right, I had opened the file in openrefine and it rendered it without them, but they are definitely there. Used a proper file-handle and it now works - thank you very much.